# Cmake within msys2 not able to find openssl

Tags: cmake, openssl, msys2, pacman-package-manager

I've installed openssl into msys2 using pacman:

```
pacman -S openssl
```

However Cmake (within msys2) is still not able to find openssl libraries...

```
CMake Error at C:/Langs/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY)
```

What are the proper values for OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR and/or OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY? I've tried everything I can find inside msys that contains openssl libraries.

```
/mingw64/include/openssl/  
/mingw64/bin/  
/mingw64/
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue was that the end of the cmake command had:

```
-D MSYS2_FOLDER=c:/msys64
```

Which was the default. But the proper value for my system was:

```
-D MSYS2_FOLDER=c:/langs/msys64
```

the proper value for OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR was:

```
c:/langs/msys64/mingw64
```

Comment: Ah, you're awesome. I had to change the drive for mine: `MSYS2_FOLDER=D:/mypathto/msys64`